# Previous and next link in wordpress for the same category

Tags: php, wordpress

In single.php file of wordpress there is a navigation section to link the next or previous post.
This is the code I used for the previous/next post. I would like that these links open the same category posts (in my example below "2" is the ID of the category):

```
<?php previous_post_link('%link', '<i class="icon-chevron-left pull-left"></i>', TRUE, '2'); ?>
<?php next_post_link('%link', '<i class="icon-chevron-right pull-right"></i>', TRUE, '2'); ?>
```

Why it is not working?

Answer (score 4):

The fourth parameter is for the categories you want to exclude, so in this case you're excluding the category `2`.

Removing the fourth parameter should do the trick:

```
<?php previous_post_link('%link', '<i class="icon-chevron-left pull-left"></i>', TRUE); ?>
<?php next_post_link('%link', '<i class="icon-chevron-right pull-right"></i>', TRUE); ?>
```

Reference: [next_post_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) and [previous_post_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link).

---

**Update**

Get adjacent post links just for one subcategory is not so simple, but you can apply the method described in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/178789/69071), using the filter `wp_get_object_terms` to refer just to the category wanted.

So, having the ID of the category you want (in this case I use `2` like your example), this would be the code to put in your `single.php` file:

```
<?php
    // set the category ID wanted
    $GLOBALS['just_this_category'] = 2;
    // add filter for navigation links
    add_filter('wp_get_object_terms', 'my_custom_post_navigation'); ?>
?>

<!-- navigation links -->
<?php previous_post_link('%link', '<i class="icon-chevron-left pull-left"></i>', TRUE); ?>
<?php next_post_link('%link', '<i class="icon-chevron-right pull-right"></i>', TRUE); ?>

<?php // remove filter just after navigation links
    remove_filter('wp_get_object_terms', 'my_custom_post_navigation');
?>
```

And this the filter function for your `functions.php` file:

```
function my_custom_post_navigation($terms){
    global $just_this_category;

    if( array_search($just_this_category, (array)$terms) !== FALSE )

        return array($just_this_category);

    return array();

}
```

As you can see I used the global variable `$just_this_category` to pass the category ID to the filter function.

Obviously for every post you need to set a different category ID (you can retrieve it automatically, but how to depends on how you manage your categories).

Comment: But it doesn't work anyway. It shows all the posts and not only post of one category.

Comment: Do these posts belong to more than one category? As the reference says: "If the post is in both the parent and subcategory, or more than one term, the next post link will lead to the next post in any of those terms".

Comment: You're right. They belong to more than one category. Is there the possibility to link for just one sub-category?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Ciao! :)